# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return customer().fullname }" - facing in magento2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento, magento2

I am getting this error and stack trace in console in checkout page and unable to proceed checkout.

```
knockout.js:3381 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return customer().fullname }"
Message: customer is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2982), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:4381)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2173)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2140)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2101)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1954)
    at init (knockout.js:4380)
    at knockout.js:3358
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1470)
    at knockout.js:3357
```

I am facing this error in magento2.3.5-p1.
Anyone has suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
if: function(){
        if(customer().fullname) {
                return customer().fullname 
        }
        return null;
}
```